# why print('NaN') shows different result from print(float('NaN'))

Tags: python

```
print('NaN') 
'NaN'
```

but

```
 print(float('NaN'))
 'nan'
```

why this works like this and what is the difference between "NaN" and 'nan'

Comment: The numerican not-a-number is always `'nan'` using lowercase.

Comment: @Oighea `'nan'` is not the same as `float('NaN')` a.k.a. `nan` and it isn't case-sensitive – `float('nAn')` or any case-variation would result in the same `nan`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Python's `NaN` (Not a Number) is represented as a float (from [IEEE 754 floating-point standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)).

Therefore when you enter `'NaN'` it will remain a `str`:

```
>>> 'NaN'
'NaN'
>>> type('NaN')
<class 'str'>
```

But when you attempt to convert a `str` representation of a `float` into a `float`, it will respond will the corresponding `float` representation of that `str`:

```
>>> float('123.45')
123.45
>>> type(float('123.45'))
<class 'float'>
```

And since `'NaN'` is, technically, an identifiable `str` representation of a `float`, it converts without error:

```
>>> float('NaN')
nan
>>> type(float('NaN'))
<class 'float'>
```

Comment: It is part of the IEEE 754 that it is a float value of its own, it is not specific to Python

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Thank you for the info, I've added a link to it.

Answer (score 3):

The first instance `'NaN'` is a string. It has no numerical meaning.

```
>>> type('NaN')
<class 'str'>
```

The second instance is the [IEEE 754 *Not A Number* value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), it is a float.

```
>>> type(float('NaN'))
<class 'float'>
```

The representation of `float('NaN')` is always `nan`, regardless of the letter cases used to create it.

```
# Those all work
float('NaN')
float('nan')
float('nAn')
```

Note that the `nan` value is also accessible through the `math` module, like `inf` which is another value that comes from the IEEE 754 standard.

```
from math import nan, inf
```

Answer (score 1):

@Olivier Melançon is right `'Nan'` returns an string `float('NaN')` returns an float

So, you can check it like below:

```
>>> import math
>>> x=float('NaN')
>>> math.isnan(x)
True
>>> x='NaN'
>>> math.isnan(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#60>", line 1, in <module>
    math.isnan(x)
TypeError: must be real number, not str
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`print('NaN')` is just printing the argument string as it is. For the `print` function, it's as same as any other string.

```
>>> type('NaN')
<class 'str'>
```

whereas, `float('NaN')` is actually a `Not A Number`, which is represented as `nan`.

```
>>> type(float('NaN'))
<class 'float'>
```